# How can I create one two column layout with draggable components?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, layout

I'm developing one ASP.NET MVC application that must show some Google Chart graphics.

I would create my layout like the table below:

```
+-----------------------+
| HEADER                |
+-----------------------+
| Graphic selector      |
+-----------------------+
| Graphic 1 | Graphic 2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Graphic 3 | Graphic 4 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Graphic 5 |           |
+-----------+-----------+
|           |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

The *Graphic selector* section contains eight checkbox that must hide or show the relative graph.

Below the *Graphic selector* section I need to show more graphics with the capability of drag and drop.

How can I perform this task?

*Note: I've tried to use one library called jQuery.gridly but there is not more documentation and I can't create the layout I want.*

Comment: Have you tried the draggable feature that jQuery UI provides?

Comment: Hi JDupont, I haven't  tried the draggable feature of jQuery UI. Fist of start with custom implementation I would try to use existent library for do that.